# SSL Socket between Android and java

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, sslsocketfactory

I am currently working on a university little project in which we should make an android application which can communicate with a java SSL Socket. I am kinda new on the SSL connections, I red about keystores and stuff but I didn't really get it.

This is the Android side:

```
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;
    SSLSocket socket;
    socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    try {
        socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket("192.168.1.131", 7070);
        System.out.println("Connected!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the java server one:

```
        SSLServerSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) socketFactory.createServerSocket(7070);
        serverSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.3"});
        while (true) {
            // wait for client connection and check login information
            try {
                System.err.println("Waiting for connection...");
                SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connessione Accettata");
                // open BufferedReader for reading data from client
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                // open PrintWriter for writing data to client

                System.out.println(input);
                //PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

                //output.close();
                input.close();
                socket.close();

            } // end try
            // handle exception communicating with client
            catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Obviously the sockets don't even connect each other, what should I implement to make it work?

Comment: First you need to make sure your network will allow this.  Are you using a device or an emulator?  If you're on an emulator, that IP is wrong, it should be 10.0.2.2.  If you're using a real device make sure its on wifi, on the same network, and that your router is set to allow incoming connections to your server at that port.

Comment: @GabeSechan I am using a real device, it is connected to the same network of the pc and I am sure the server opens that port due to an nmap scan, also the ping from the pc to the mobile works... I think there is something missing in my code but Idk